# reaching data with AngularJS2 and json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic2

I need to develop an app for a conference and i'm trying to make this with Ionic2, AngularJS2 and Firebase.
I'm not starting from scratch, I clone this repository : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app.
My repository : https://github.com/wowadrien/SFGP

My problem is that I need to filter the session first by day, next by room and then by theme so I add a level in the tree of my json to sort the session by room.

I've change the code of the data provider as this :

```
processData(data: any) {
this.data = data.json();

this.data.tracks = [];

// loop through each day in the schedule
this.data.schedule.forEach((day: any) => {
  // loop through each timeline group in the day
  day.groups.forEach((group: any) => {
    // loop through each session in the timeline group
    group.sessions.forEach((session: any) => {
      //loop trough each subsession in the timeline session
        session.subsessions.forEach((subsession: any) =>{             
          subsession.speakers = [];
          if (subsession.speakerNames) {
            subsession.speakerNames.forEach((speakerName: any) => {
              let speaker = this.data.speakers.find((s: any) => s.name === speakerName);
              if (speaker) {
                subsession.speakers.push(speaker);
                speaker.subsessions = speaker.subsessions || [];
                speaker.subsessions.push(subsession);
              }
            });
          }

          if (subsession.tracks) {
            subsession.tracks.forEach((track: any) => {
              if (this.data.tracks.indexOf(track) < 0) {
                this.data.tracks.push(track);
              }
            });
          }
        });
    });
  });
});
return this.data;
}
```

It doesn't work and i've tried about 20 differents solutions since last week but none of them was good.
I'm hopeless and lonely in this project so please, I need help !

Adrien